# Execute shell on a relative path on ubuntu launcher

Tags: command-line, unity, bash, launcher

I've created this launcher that executes a shell:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=/full/path/server.sh
Name=MServer
Comment=foo
Icon=gnome-sudoku
```

I need it to execute a relative path because I don't know the full path:

```
Exec=server.sh
```

But the code above with relative path doesn't work.
How can I execute from the relative path?

Comment: Please, look at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428992/why-do-freedesktop-desktop-files-not-allow-relative-paths

Answer (score 0):

The [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428992/why-do-freedesktop-desktop-files-not-allow-relative-paths) @FedonKadifeli has suggested helped me.

The possible solution can be:

```
Exec=sh -e -c "exec \\"\\$(dirname \\"\\$0\\")/.sh/server.sh\\";$SHELL" %k
```

Explaining the command:

The snippet below will get the dir name of who is executing that, therefore the launcher dir name

```
$(dirname \\"\\$0\\")
```

So appending the desired path, will make this execute relative path.